# Could someone explain this results section from a study? (very elementary question)

Tags: statistics

Sorry for the beginner level question. Could someone explain what the below means?

---

On average, more than 4 weights per week were entered into the CTM program. A significant difference in mean within subject weight loss was found between the control group ($n = 65$; $0.5 ± 4.4$ kilograms (kg)) and the CTM intervention group ($n = 70$; $2.6 ± 5.9$ kg) over the first year ($p = 0.019$). Nonparametric tests (Mann-Whitney $U$) revealed very similar results ($p = 0.02$).

---

I *think* that this section ($n = 65$; $0.5 ± 4.4$ kilograms (kg)) means:

*there were 65 people in the group

*the average weight lost was .5 kg

*4.4 is the standard deviation of the weights within that group?

Is that correct?

(It's the section entitled "3.2. Year 1 Results" in this paper: https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jobe/2015/763680/)

thanks for any info!

Comment: Dunno, I had no problem copy.pasting the missing parts (but I nevertheless added LaTeX-dollars around them)

Answer (score 1):

I know little about statistics, but from what I can gather, the Mann-Whitley U test is similar (and in some cases, more robust) than the Student's T test.  You can read more about the Mann-Whitley test here: [Mann-Whitley U Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test)